Keyboard opening and closing immediately due to multiple rebuilds when tapping on TextFormField
For debugging purposes, I had put a print statement inside the build method and I noticed that the whole widget was rebuilding multiple times when the TextFormField was tapped.

The keyboard opens up, and then immediately closes.
This is my code:
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({super.key});

  static Route<void> route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());
  }

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _selectUrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!kReleaseMode) {
      _emailController.text = '';
      _passwordController.text = '';
      _selectUrl.text = baseUrl;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                      20.0,
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/logo.png',
                      color: isDarkMode(context)
                          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
                          : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter your email',
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter your password',
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AuthenticationFailureState) {
                      _emailController.text = state.fields['email'] ?? '';
                      _passwordController.text = state.fields['password'] ?? '';
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Login failed'),
                                content: Text(
                                  state.errorMessage,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.error,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ));
                          });
                    } else if (state is AuthenticationSuccessState) {
                      context
                          .read<CalendarDataBloc>()
                          .add(FetchCalendarEvents());

                      context.read<HomeBloc>().add(FetchCheckedInEvents());

                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
                    }
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return state is AuthenticationLoadingState &&
                            (state).isLoading
                        ? const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          )
                        : SizedBox(
                            child: FilledButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
                                    .add(
                                  LoginUser(
                                    _emailController.text.trim(),
                                    _passwordController.text.trim(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                'Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is my main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SecureStorageService.instance;
  await HiveStorageService.init();
  final ThemeMode initialThemeMode = HiveStorageService().getThemeMode();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await FirebaseNotifications().initNotifications();
  }

  if (!kDebugMode) {
    FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
    };

    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };

    await SentryFlutter.init(
      (options) {
        options.dsn =
            '';
        options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
        options.profilesSampleRate = 1.0;
        options.environment = kReleaseMode ? 'production' : 'profile';
      },
      appRunner: () => runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc()..add(const AppStarted()),
          ),
          BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(create: (context) => HomeBloc()),
          BlocProvider<CalendarBloc>(create: (context) => CalendarBloc()),
          BlocProvider<CalendarDataBloc>(
              create: (context) => CalendarDataBloc()),
          BlocProvider(
              create: (_) => ThemeCubit()..setThemeMode(initialThemeMode)),
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      )),
    );
  } else {
    runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc()..add(const AppStarted()),
        ),
        BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(create: (context) => HomeBloc()),
        BlocProvider<CalendarBloc>(create: (context) => CalendarBloc()),
        BlocProvider<CalendarDataBloc>(create: (context) => CalendarDataBloc()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => ThemeCubit()..setThemeMode(initialThemeMode)),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const platform = MethodChannel('in.co.ezerx.sales_iq/check');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: getTheme(context, currentTheme: context.watch<ThemeCubit>().state),
      home: Platform.isAndroid
          ? FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: _isDeveloperOptionsEnabled(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text('Error checking developer options'),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.data == true && kReleaseMode) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Developer options are enabled'),
                          Text('Please disable developer options to continue'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AuthenticationSuccessState) {
                      return const HomeScreen();
                    } else {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    }
                  });
                }
              })
          : BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is AuthenticationSuccessState) {
                return const HomeScreen();
              } else {
                return LoginScreen();
              }
            }),
      onGenerateRoute: (setting) => _generateRoute(setting),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _isDeveloperOptionsEnabled() async {
    try {
      final bool result = await platform.invokeMethod('checkDevOptions');
      return result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      errorPrint(e.message);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Route _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    Widget screen;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        screen = LoginScreen();
        break;
      case '/home':
        screen = const HomeScreen();
        break;
      case '/settings':
        screen = const SettingsScreen();
        break;
      case '/checkin':
        screen = const Checkin();
        break;
      case '/checkout':
        screen = Checkout();
        break;
      case '/prospect':
        screen = Prospect();
        break;
      case '/create_event':
        screen = CreateEvent();
        break;
      case '/reschedule':
        screen = Reschedule();
        break;
      case '/prospect_list':
        screen = ProspectList();
        break;
      case '/profile':
        screen = const Profile();
        break;
      case '/dashboard':
        screen = const Dashboard();
        break;
      case '/cumulative_dashboard':
        screen = const CumulativeDashboard();
        break;
      default:
        screen = LoginScreen();
    }

    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => screen,
      settings: settings,
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
        const end = Offset.zero;
        const curve = Curves.ease;

        var tween =
            Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        return SlideTransition(
          position: animation.drive(tween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I agree, but could this be a possible reason for this error?
I've removed it, but the issue is still present.

It'happen because the TextFormFeild controller changed the state.

@DipakPrajapati I tried by removing the controllers temporarily as well. But didn't fix.

Check Bloc State Changes If your AuthenticationBloc is emitting new states frequently (such as AuthenticationLoadingState), it could be triggering rebuilds too often.

But, BlocBuilder is only wrapping a small section of the screen. It is not affecting the entire screen.

Convert your stateless widgets into State full widgets override init method.
Remove your build method code and covert to like this.
 @override
  initState() {
       if (!kReleaseMode) {
      _emailController.text = '';
      _passwordController.text = '';
      _selectUrl.text = baseUrl;
},}


have already tried it. still the same issue. One thing that I noticed was: initState() as well was getting called multiple times (not sure why). I had put a print statement inside the initState function. It got printed 2 times in the console on tapping the textfield.
